# Validator for multiple types in grails

Tags: grails, constraints, validation

In a domain class I have a value from an enum which represents an email address or a URL

```
class Contact{
  ContactType contact
  String value
}

enum ContactType{
  EMAIL,
  URL
}
```

I'm trying to use the built in grails EmailConstraint and UrlConstraint classes to validate:

```
static constraints = {
  value(validator: {
    ContactType.validate(obj, val, errors)
  })
}
```

I managed to make it work by making some assumptions reading grails source:

```
Constraint constraint = new EmailConstraint()
constraint.setPropertyName "value"
constraint.setOwningClass obj.class
constraint.setParameter true
constraint.validate(obj, obj.value, errors)
```

But I find this very ugly, so I was wondering if anyone can offer a better solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might implement a custom constraint for this case using http://www.grails.org/plugin/constraints. The new constraint class might delegate internally to EmailConstraint or to a kind of "URLConstraint" depending on the enum value.

Using this approach, your domain class stays clean an small, validation details are seperated into a different class.

Comment: Good idea, thanks, but still, the constraint code keeps bothering me.

Comment: you could 'groovyfy' the above code to: new EmailConstraint(propertyName:'value', owningClass:obj.class, paramater: true).validate(obj, obj.value,errors)